# How to simultaneously run Android speech to text and another activity which uses camera

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, affdex-sdk

I am new to Android and am trying to develop an application which would capture the speaker's facial expressions via camera and simultaneously convert speech to text. I am using Affectiva's affdex API for real time facial emotions recognition. 
Whenever I try to launch the speech to text module via a button, the facial recognition stops, the STT modules completes and then the facial recognition module restarts. I want to have them work simultaneously.

Comment: Only one app can record audio at a time, so make sure the camera app does not access the microphone.

Comment: The camera doesn't record audio, the STT module directly converts the speech through RecognizerIntent. But that needs to be as a focus activity, thus the camera module stops

Comment: @Kaarel is a great source of advice.... given that , why is it not possible to independently control 2 processes ... #1 get the camera control and capture camera frames ... #2 start an AudioRecorder, capturing an audio buffer -> bytes -> encoder -> STT API ... more on #1 at https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/  "see OnImageAvailableListener"  ... more on #2  https://github.com/rowntreerob/Google-speech-Opus-Recorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/OpusRecorder.java#L168  - note that this audiobuffer is delegated to google-STT

Comment: So just to clarify, is your speech-to-text logic in a different activity than your facial expression recognition logic?  Obviously, you can't have two foreground activities at the same time. Try putting them in the same activity, or put one in a service.

Comment: Yes, both logic are in the same, main activity. the STT module requires to be run on a different thread.